# JMeter doesn't fail on BeanShell errors

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

In my company we use JMeter as part of our release pipeline to run various tests (smoke, load, etc). As now I'm creating more complicated test scenarios, I'm using a lot of BeanShell and I'm concerned by the fact that JMeter seems to be totally fine with failed BeanShell scripts, and I'd like to find a way to fail tests when BeanShell fails.

If a syntax error is present, the script will fail, report to the log file, but it won't prevent the whole test suite to succeed, as long as the missing BeanShell execution don't trigger anything else to fail. Example (click for full size image):

[image: JMeter screenshot]

As seen above, I have a sampler with a BeanShell postprocessor that contains a syntax error. When executed the error logged and increases the error counter on the top, but that's all. If the user doesn't notice that, the error will slip to our release process, making our tests less reliable. If I run JMeter with the command line, this is the result:

```
Writing log file to: /home/user/jmeter/jmeter.log
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using Bad BeanShell Test.jmx
Starting the test @ Fri Feb 24 12:23:11 CET 2017 (1487935391815)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary =      2 in 00:00:01 =    1.9/s Avg:   382 Min:    29 Max:   736 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Fri Feb 24 12:23:13 CET 2017 (1487935393168)
... end of run
```

Again, seems all right, only the log file to find out something is wrong. And adding a post-test script to look for errors on the file is not a good self-contained test case.

I tried a BeanShell Listener but it doesn't seem to expose the results of the script compilation/execution ([SampleEvent](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleEvent.html) doesn't contain useful info), and even after a lot of searching, I found no way to do it at all.

It could be a listener, an assertion, custom Java code on a plugin, a command line configuration, anything as long as I can add it once on my test suite, and at least trigger one error or abort the suite to ensure it will be investigated.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to get Beanshell PostProcessor failure in the test results is amending parent sampler result setting it to "Failure" at the Beanshell script beginning and to "Success" at the script failure, something like:

```
prev.setSuccessful(false);
//your main Beanshell code goes here
prev.setSuccessful(true);
```

So if any Beanshell error will occur in-between these `prev.setSuccessful` methods - the parent sampler will be failed.

---

Given your test relies on scripting I would recommend switching to [JRS223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/), it will be much better from performance perspective, see [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information, benchmarks, and scripting best practices.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently faster and got better error reporting, which is nice, however this approach still requires active effort to code the script in a specific way to capture such failures. As a developer, I see it as a job for the platform itself, after all the interpreter was executed and knows if errors were present, so why can't such information be used to abort the test or set a failure instead of forcing the developer to use tricks to reach the same result? Anyway, thanks for your answer, it is my best alternative so far.